Beat frequency equation of coupled pendulums with same natural frequency displaced to unequal extents
When 2 pendula of same natural frequency connected by a common spring are displaced to unequal extents, I understand that this causes the superposition of 2 normal modes: Parallel and symmetrical, which causes beat phenomena. Is there an equation relating the difference in displacement and beat frequency, and could you please explain it? Thank you!

This is covered in many texts on oscillations. What is preventing you from finding it out yourself?

Here is a short explanation.
A simple pendulum consisting of a point mass $m$ on a massless rod of length $L$ hanging downward in a conventional gravitational field $g$ will exhibit oscillations with natural frequency $\omega_1 = \sqrt{g/L}$ with the usual assumptions of small amplitude, no damping, etc.
Likewise, two masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ connected by a spring with constant $k$ will exibit oscillations with natural frequency $\omega_2 = \sqrt{k(m_1 + m_2)/(m_1 m_2)}$ (assuming my reference is correct).
If you arrange the masses in the way you describe you can obviously excite the pendulum mode but not the spring mode by displacing the masses equally.
If you displace the masses in an equal and opposite way, you will excite something like the spring mode, although the frequency may be affected by the pendulum effects, not 100% sure.  Certainly if $\omega_2 >> \omega_1$ then you will basically see the masses oscillate out of phase at frequency $\omega_2$.
Now if you displace one mass a bit more than the other, you will get a superposition of modes.  Anytime there are two output frequencies near each other, you will see a beat phenomenon as the frequencies alternate between adding and cancelling.  This beat frequency will be equal to $\omega_2 - \omega_1$ assuming $\omega_2 > \omega_1$.  But it won't be noticeable unless the frequencies are reasonably close together in a numerical sense.

Hi, thanks for your response. I would like to clarify some details in your last paragraph: what if w2 = w1, ie the natural frequencies of both pendulums are exactly the same? How would the beat frequency be expressed due to unequal displacements? Also, if I am not wrong, the equation beat frequency = w2 - w1 only applies to pendulums with unequal natural frequencies.
And, you also mentioned that beat phenomena won't be noticeable unless frequencies are reasonably close. Do you by any chance know how close they'd have to be? Thank you!

Or is beat frequency only dependent on the natural frequency difference b/w the 2 pendulums?

Frequency is, to first order, independent of displacement. Higher displacement gives you higher amplitudes but at the same frequency.  If $\omega_2 = \omega_1$ I am not quite sure what the result would look like, but you would not see beats because seeing beats requires two different frequencies that are close to each other.  How close is close?  Well the $\omega$ are in units of rad/sec.  Convert to Hz by dividing by $2 \pi$.   I would estimate you can easily see something physically if the difference is on the order of 0.1 - 1 Hz.

I see, thank you so much! You have been a great help.

You are welcome!
